PieCloudDB error: could not open file for reading: No such file or directory
When using psql to connect to the PieCloudDB Community Edition, I tried to import data into the database with the COPY FROM command but encountered the following error:
ERROR: could not open file "/home/pieclouddb-ce/sampledata/data.csv" for reading: No such file or directory

However, when I checked the path with the ls command, I didn't find any wrong. How can I resolve this problem?

I solved it. PieCloudDB Community Edition adopts Containerized Deployment. My data is outside the container and I need to use \copy from rather than copy from.
